# Vector not dereferencing?

Tags: c++, pointers, vector

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
#include <vector>

int **function(vector<int> *nums, int rows){
  int **output = new int*[3];
  int index;
  for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++){
    for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++){
      index = (3*i)+j;
      output[i][j] = nums[index];
    }
  }
  return output;
}

int main(void){
  int array[3][3] = {{1,4,3},
                     {4,2,6},
                     {7,3,7}};
  vector<int> nums;
  for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++){
    for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++){
      nums.push_back(array[i][j]);
    }
  }

  int **dbl = function(&nums,3);
  for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++){
    for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++){
      cout << dbl[i][j] << " ";
    }
    cout << endl;
  }
}
```

So I'm trying to get a 2d array into a vector and put it into a double pointer, but when I try to dereference nums with index, I get an error of assigning int from vector. Shouldn't the vector be dereferenced automatically? I can't do it with any other way; it's a part of a larger project that uses vectors.

Comment: `nums` is not a vector. It is a pointer to a vector. You probably want `int **function(vector<int> & num` and `function(nums, 3)`

Comment: Don't use naked pointers unless you absolutely, positively *have* to (legacy APIs for example). C++'s references and smart pointers are those things that are really a no-brainer in how much cleaner your code gets once you use them. As such, `new` really should no longer appear in C++11 code...

Answer (score 2):

Your function `function()` takes a pointer to a `vector` (an array of `vector`) but you have only one vector.

Also note that `rows` elements should be allocated for `output` instead of `3` and arrays should be allocated for each rows.

What you want may be this:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
#include <vector>

int **function(const vector<int>& nums, int rows){ // use reference instead of pointer
  int **output = new int*[rows]; // allocate rows elements
  int index;
  for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++){
    output[i] = new int[3]; // allocate each row
    for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++){
      index = (3*i)+j;
      output[i][j] = nums[index]; // now index applies to the vector instead of the pointer (array of vector)
    }
  }
  return output;
}

int main(void){
  int array[3][3] = {{1,4,3},
                     {4,2,6},
                     {7,3,7}};
  vector<int> nums;
  for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++){
    for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++){
      nums.push_back(array[i][j]);
    }
  }

  int **dbl = function(nums,3); // don't use pointer: use reference instead
  for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++){
    for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++){
      cout << dbl[i][j] << " ";
    }
    cout << endl;
  }
}
```

If you want to use a pointer to a vector, dereference that first to access elements of vector:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
#include <vector>

int **function(vector<int> *nums, int rows){
  int **output = new int*[rows]; // allocate rows elements
  int index;
  for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++){
    output[i] = new int[3]; // allocate each row
    for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++){
      index = (3*i)+j;
      output[i][j] = (*nums)[index]; // dereference the pointer
      // alternative way
      // output[i][j] = nums->at(index);
    }
  }
  return output;
}

int main(void){
  int array[3][3] = {{1,4,3},
                     {4,2,6},
                     {7,3,7}};
  vector<int> nums;
  for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++){
    for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++){
      nums.push_back(array[i][j]);
    }
  }

  int **dbl = function(&nums,3);
  for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++){
    for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++){
      cout << dbl[i][j] << " ";
    }
    cout << endl;
  }
}
```

Comment: Note also that the line `int **output = new int*[3];` does not fully do the job! Each of the three pointers then needs allocation, with something like: `for (int row = 0; row < 3; ++row) output[row] = new int[3];`.

Comment: Thanks for the replies guys, I'd tried both methods Mike pointed out and neither worked, but it turns out it was just a matter of memory allocation like Adrian said...oops

Comment: @AdrianMole Thank you, applied that.